# Grid Not Scaling or Changing

Tags: transforms, units

I am trying to do a quick project, I have watch hours of tutorials and followed what they are doing but I cannot replicate it in anyway shape or form.

I need to rescale my grid to equal 1 inch but when I do the grid doesn't change when I change the dimensions of my cube it get super small.

This is what I do:

1- Scene --> Units --> Unit System (Imperial)/ Length (inches)

2- Select my object

3- Hit N

4- Set the dimensions

The thing is on the tutorials the floor grid will show 1 inch squares. mine just stays the same no matter what.[image: What the grid looks like in comparison to a 2"x2"x2" cube]

Comment: You'd have to change that on the Viewport Overlays menu dropdown

Comment: @JohnEason I go to that tab and it shows that the Scale is set to 1 inch
If the scene is if the scene is 1 inch and cube is 2"x2" then that should be taking up 4 squares but it doesnt even cover 1.

I should also not that on the scale in the image its set at 0.025 but if change it to 1 then it becomes some crazy number

Comment: I've just again checked here since I usually use metric. If you set the units to Imperial, the Length to inches and the Unit Scale to 1/12 you seem to get the result you want without changing the overlay settings at all!